# How to show that exactly one of the following inequality systems has a solution?

Tags: inequality, optimization, linear-programming

This is from a homework set of my optimization class.

> Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times n}$. Show that exactly one of the following inequality systems has a solution:
>   $$
> \mathbf{I}: \,\,\,Ax \leq 0, \,\,\,\,x\geq 0, \,\,\,\ \sum_{i=1}^{n}x_i=1
> $$
>   $$
> \mathbf{II}: \,\,\,A^Ty > 0, \,\,\,\,y\geq 0, \,\,\,\ \sum_{i=1}^{m}y_i=1
> $$

---

We cannot apply [Farka's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Farkas%27_lemma) directly because the first problem in Farkas lemma is equality:

$$
\textbf{I}: \,\,\,Ax =b, \,\,\,\,x\geq 0
$$

$$
\textbf{II}: \,\,\,A^Ty \leq 0, \,\,\,\,b^Ty> 0
$$

Comment: @Saeed: May I ask what book you are reading on? It would be relatively easy to find an answer if one knows where your exercise is from.

Comment: @Saeed this is a community; perhaps you could go over your old questions and mark the ones that have received good answers as answered.